# Inconsistent results with java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread class which implements runnable and an int counter as instance variable. Two synchronized methods add and sub. When I run my test class somehow it is printing wrong results once in couple of times. As far  as I understand when a method is synchronized, entire object will be locked for accessing by other threads, with this logic every time we should get same results right? Some how that is not the case. Am I missing something?

My machine is Windows 7, 64 bit.

```
 public class ThreadClass implements Runnable {

        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            add();
            sub();
        }

        public synchronized void add() {
            System.out.println("ADD counter" + (counter = counter + 1));
        }

        public synchronized void sub() {
            System.out.println("SUB counter" + (counter = counter - 1));
        }
    }
```

Testclass

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadClass tc = new ThreadClass();
        Thread tc0 = new Thread(tc);
        tc0.start();
        tc0.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        Thread tc1 = new Thread(tc);
        tc1.start();
        tc1.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        Thread tc2 = new Thread(tc);
        tc2.start();
        tc2.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    }
}
```

Results

```
ADD counter1
ADD counter2
SUB counter1
SUB counter0
ADD counter1
SUB counter0
```

**Note:** You may need to do couple of runs to produce this inconsistency.

Comment: You should change the printline in the `add` method to `ADD counter` so it's easier to see what is going on and maybe also provide and id for each thread so you can see which output comes from which thread.

Comment: @ChrisWue. I ran again with updated System.out. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronization will indeed mean that all threads will block waiting to acquire a lock before they can enter the synchronized block.  Only one thread can ever have the lock on the object, so only one thread can be in the `add()` or `sub()` methods.

However, this does not imply anything else about the ordering of threads.  You're starting three threads - the only guarantee is that they won't stomp on each other by running the `add` or `sub` methods at once.  Thread 1 can call `add()`, then thread 3 can call `add()`, then thread 2 can call `add()`, then they can all call `sub()`.  Or they could all call `add()` and then `sub()` each.  Or any mixture - the only requirement being that each thread calls `add()` before it calls `sub()` and that no two threads will ever call `add()` or `sub()` while another thread is in that method.

Aside: it can be, in some cases, bad form to synchronize on `this`, as it's public - it's often preferred to use an internal private `Object` to lock on so that no other callers can take your lock and violate any locking strategies you have designed.

Comment: I tried with private Object lock also (the version I posted is last version of couple of , same results. Now my real question is, can any program with instance variable will be thread-safe? my assumption is because of priorities set, it should execute in order. If I need to make sure threads triggered in same order should execute in same order, how can I achieve it?

Comment: @thinksteep: Why are you using threads if every thread must wait for another one to be finished before starting? You end up having a sequence of operations that could be executed in a single thread.

Comment: @thinksteep: yes, the private lock will indeed give you the same results.  That's a code style issue that you may wish to get in the habit of, not a bug.  Anyway, priorities are a **hint**, not a guarantee.  If you need to ensure a particular order, you need to handle your own scheduling.

Comment: @JBNizet, I am under impression that it will execute in sequence because of synchronized and wrote this test program to make sure my understanding is correct or not. Now I am getting clarity with the answers from community.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, thank you for explaining, could you point me to any example of using scheduling? I want to try that. As per Bills comment for Ben S response, if OS is super power on allocating thread priority, can we safely say the scheduling mechanism we are going to implement will work fine?

Comment: @thinksteep: What I mean is, if you know that you need thread 1 to execute, then thread 2, then thread 3, then you should probably use the existing synchronization primitives to guide you there.  For example, take a lock and look at an `int` field.  If it's `0`, then thread 1 can do its work and increment it.  If it's `1`, then thread 2 can do **it's** work, and increment it, etc.  The other threads should yield until it's the value they expect.

Answer (score 5):

Your results look correct.

During the execution of the methods, an exclusive lock on the object is obtained, but between the `add()` and `sub()` calls, the threads can freely interleave.

If you end up with a total of `0` after all the threads have run, then none of them overwrote eathother and the access to `counter` was synchronized.

If you wish to have `counter` only go from `0` to `1` sequentially and never hit `2`, then do the following (which will render the method-level synchronization redundant so long as no other classes are involved):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronize(this) {
        add();
        sub();
    }
}
```

However, this makes the whole point of the threads useless since you could do that in a single-threaded loop.

Comment: I agree with end up with total of 0 statement, but if I understand synchronization correctly, I shouldn't get 2, because add/sub are in same thread which locked the object initially for addition. If not, what is the real use of having Synchronized keyword there?  You see what I am struggling to understand?

Comment: When the `run()` method is executing on one of the threads, it doesn't own the lock (`run()` isn't synchronized). When it encounters the `add()` call, it attempts to grab the lock. If the lock isn't available it waits. Once the `add()` call finishes, it releases the lock. At this point another thread might be waiting for it and gets to grab the lock before the other thread's `sub()` has a chance to execute. This is why two `add()` calls can happen in a row.

Comment: Although I agree with your explanation, it doesn't explain how the counter can go from 2 to 0 without going to 1. Why does System.out.println reorder the lines?

Comment: @JBNizet Because it's probably buffered internally and one high priority thread might be adding his message before another lower priority thread.

Comment: The answer is correct. One thread could come in, lock the object, add the number, unlock the object and then be suspended by the operating system. Then another thread could come in and do the same. I think you're making the assumption that the operating system will have 100% respect for your thread priority, which is not the case. You can not count on controlling behavior this way, for example, if there are multiple cores all three threads could be executing even though they have different priory levels.

Comment: @JB Nizet: it is not possible to go from 2 to 0 under the code he posted.  I suspect his output is from an execution where `sub` was not synchronized.  There is some evidence for this conjecture: the original code he posted had the `sub` method's `synchronized` keyword placed in a location where the code would not compile, meaning he typed the synchronized keyword into his comment, after having pasted a version of the code that actually compiled.  Record of his original post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8811535/revisions

Comment: @ChrisWue: the call to System.out.println is synchronized, so it's guaranteed that the call which makes the counter go from 2 to 1 is guaranteed to be made before the call which makes it go from 1 to 0.

Comment: @Mike Clark: That's an explanation I agree with. Thank you.

Comment: @BenS: Thank you for your answer, this discussion and Edward answer helped me in understanding this concept fully. If two answer option is there, I could have accepted you both, this time I am accepting Edward.

Comment: @MikeClark: I think the argument is that it's not possible for value to go from 2 to 0 without having been through 1.  (the original post read "SUB counter2\nSUBcounter0", but has since been edited.)  I think we agree all agree that the code could end up getting called as: `add(); add(); add(); sub(); sub(); sub();`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm sorry I was not clear.  My point is that, with the posted code (both methods synchronized), the logging output could never show a direct transition from 2 to 0.  When both methods are synchronized, an intermediate 1 must be printed between 2 and 0.  His original post contained output which jumped directly from 2 to 0 without showing an intermediate 1.  This is impossible with the code posted.  Thus his originally posted program could not have generated his originally posted output.  He has since edited the output, which makes the comment chain confusing.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with either set of results. They are both perfectly consistent with what your code does. The running order of multiple threads is not guaranteed.

Your 'synchronized' methods ensure you get valid results -- each call to `add` in fact adds one and each call to `sub` in fact subtracts one. Without them, you could get a final result other than zero.