# Java thread with the highest priority does not get executed

Tags: java, multithreading

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Semaphore semp = new Semaphore(1);
        for (int facultyNO = 1; facultyNO <= 10; facultyNO++) {
            final int NO = facultyNO;
            Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            semp.acquire();
                            System.out.println("No." + NO + " grab a candy");
                            Bowl.candy--;
                            System.out.println("Candy num left:" + Bowl.candy);
                            semp.release();
                            Thread.sleep((long) (1000));
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread faculty = new Thread(run);
            faculty.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            faculty.start();
        }
        Thread TA = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (Bowl.candy < 0) {
                        semp.acquire();
                        System.out.println("TA fills the candy bowl");
                        Bowl.candy = 10;
                        System.out.println("Candy num left:" + Bowl.candy);
                        semp.release();
                    }
                }
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        TA.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        TA.start();
    }
}
```

Bowl.java:

```
public class Bowl {
    static int candy = 10;
}
```

I give the thread "TA" the highest priority because I want it to be executed as soon as Bowl.candy=0 to fill the bowl. However, the console prints:

```
No.2 grab a candy
Candy num left:9
No.1 grab a candy
Candy num left:8
No.4 grab a candy
Candy num left:7
No.6 grab a candy
Candy num left:6
No.7 grab a candy
Candy num left:5
No.8 grab a candy
Candy num left:4
No.3 grab a candy
Candy num left:3
No.5 grab a candy
Candy num left:2
No.10 grab a candy
Candy num left:1
No.9 grab a candy
Candy num left:0
No.2 grab a candy
Candy num left:-1
No.1 grab a candy
Candy num left:-2
No.4 grab a candy
Candy num left:-3
No.6 grab a candy
Candy num left:-4
No.7 grab a candy
Candy num left:-5
No.8 grab a candy
Candy num left:-6
No.3 grab a candy
Candy num left:-7
No.5 grab a candy
Candy num left:-8
No.10 grab a candy
Candy num left:-9
No.9 grab a candy
Candy num left:-10
```

It seems like the code within `if (Bowl.candy < 0)` never gets executed. Why?

Comment: Thread priorities are NOT hard rules which OS schedulers follow. If you have inter-thread dependence (like one thread should execute before other), then essentially you don't need threading. Threading specially deals with that fact that computation can be done independent. If you are looking for shared states between threads, you need to use other concurrency mechanisms. This might help you more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811535/inconsistent-results-with-java-threads

Answer (score 3):

You have to acquire lock before accessing the variable in this case:

```
semp.acquire();
if (Bowl.candy < 0) {
    System.out.println("TA fills the candy bowl");
    Bowl.candy = 10;
    System.out.println("Candy num left:" + Bowl.candy);
}
semp.release();
```

Another options:

`Bowl.candy` has to be declared as `volatile` otherwise there is no guarantee that other threads can see changes to this variable. Or `Bowl.candy` has to be accessed in a `synchronized` block only.

Comment: Isn't this what the semaphore is doing?

Comment: @Michael, semaphore guarantees visibility if you access variable after you acquired it. But you access `Bowl.candy` before acquiring the lock: `if (Bowl.candy < 0) { semp.acquire(); ...`, so it sees 9 all the time

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a race condition problem. You're checking the value, then I suspect another thread has already taken the semaphore, so you can't change the value.

If you change your semaphore to wrap the check and the assignment, your result will be slightly better.

```
Thread TA = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        while (true) {
            semp.acquire();
            if (candy < 0) {
                System.out.println("TA fills the candy bowl");
                Bowl.candy = 10;
                System.out.println("Candy num left:" + Bowl.candy);
            }
            semp.release();
        }
    }
    //...
});
```

However, because of scheduling issues, you'll get results like this:

```
Candy num left:2
No.2 grab a candy
Candy num left:1
No.3 grab a candy
Candy num left:0
No.5 grab a candy
Candy num left:-1  //!!!
No.6 grab a candy
Candy num left:-2  //!!!
TA fills the candy bowl
```

As Nambari points out, you probably don't want to solve this problem with multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks. I tried you solution and it worked! Every time candy=0, it will get filled. I do not know why this happens....

Comment: @XINDILI: If a solution is working for you, you need to accept the answer.

Comment: @XINDILI I would take it with a pinch of salt. Run it multiple times to verify it does what you expect. Perhaps write a unit test. The best you can hope for, I think, is that it's platform-dependent. I've already witnessed it not working for myself (dropping below zero) so the danger definitely exists.